# how to get column width changing with the inner text length in recyclerview

Tags: android, gridview, layout, android-recyclerview

I have to represent some short sentences in `TextViews`. I did that using a `recyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` and setting each sentence on a `TextView` on each cell of the grid. The thing is that I would like that each cell of the grid change its width according to the text in the `TextView`. I mean, a long sentence could take the screen full width, or if the sentence are very short, they must be on the same row.

I also tried using a `GridView` but I couldn't get the desired result either.

Any idea about how to get that?

**EDIT**

*item.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/unselected_term"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/term_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

[image: Desired layout]

This is an example of how the layout should look like. The lenght of each element won't be always the same. So I need a layout that let the larger elements having more width that the shorter ones.

Comment: can you post your xml here ? The layout which you are using for recyclerview item

Comment: @Umair Code added :)

Comment: I have updated the answer please check and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below layout will change your row item size according to your text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you want to keep no width when there is no text then remove android:minWidth attribute from textview.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this doesn't address the problem, since the elements are always in two columns. I uploaded a image to show better what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The elements on the image are just an example. The element length is going to change each time I query a database. So, maybe there are only very long elements on the recyclerview, so I  need a element per row, taking the full width. But mabe there are only short elements, so I will need having 3 or 4 per row... The order will be random

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres then you have to implement StaggeredGridLayout like suggested by another answer. If you want to implement by yourself it will take alot of your time. and you can implement that by giving every view the wrap_content width so every view will take width according to text and the whole layout will be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, the other question sugested using it. I'm trying to do it but I haven't got any similar to the desired result.  For example, If I set the `spanCount` to 3 I won't be able to have a full width element, or if I set it to 1, I won't be able to get rows width several short elements. Could you clarify to me how to solve that?

Thank you

Comment: Well we have to pass column no to staggeredview so you will have to cope with that. Only other solution is to make a custom manager which will check it's width on your text length and design your layout according to that. :)

Comment: thank you, that seems a lot of work, buuut it seems the right answer too. Thanks for your help

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres yeah exactly but i am sure you will find some alternative solution to this also .. Happy Coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Use this gradle**

`implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'`

**Try use this layout for your recycler view**

```
FlexboxLayoutManager flexLayout = new FlexboxLayoutManager( MainActivity.this );
recyclerView.setLayoutManager( flexLayout );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for your `RecycelrView`. [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) about that and use.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, please? I was playing with the StaggeredGrid but I haven't got the desired result. The problem is that the number of columns and rows that I'm gonna need is dynamic. It's going to change depending on the loaded text. I updated the question to clarify.